# How can I see all my active Orgs in the VS CLI and remove the expired ones?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

So I want to remove the expired Scratch-Orgs and get a list of my valid Orgs including the scratch orgs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So What you can do to remove the expired orgs is

```
sfdx force:org:list --clean
```

and to list all orgs you have signed into is:

```
sfdx force:org:list
```

Here I would recommand to get some aliases fixed up to make your life so much easier.